# Auto timestamp when editing column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

Trying to add an automatic timestamp to my spreadsheet. Anytime data is edited in Column "PM Status" I want an auto timestamp in column "Date Update".

```
function onEdit(event)
{ 
  var timezone = "ET";
  var timestamp_format = "MM-dd-yyyy"; // Timestamp Format. 
  var updateColName = "PM Status";
  var timeStampColName = "Date Update";
  var sheet = event.source.getSheetByName('All Leads'); //Name of the sheet where you want to run this script.


  var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex();
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName);
  var updateCol = headers[0].indexOf(updateColName); updateCol = updateCol+1;
  if (dateCol > -1 && index > 1 && editColumn == updateCol) { // only timestamp if 'Last Updated' header exists, but not in the header row itself!
    var cell = sheet.getRange(index, dateCol + 1);
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format);
    cell.setValue(date);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit(event)
{ 
  var sheet=event.source.getActiveSheet();
  if(sheet.getName()=="All Leads")
  {
    var timezone = "ET";
    var timestamp_format = "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"; // Timestamp Format. 
    var updateColName = "PM Status";
    var timeStampColName = "Date Update";
    var actRng = event.range;
    var editColumn = actRng.getColumn();
    var actRow = actRng.getRow();
    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    var dateCol = headers[0].indexOf(timeStampColName) + 1;
    var updateCol = headers[0].indexOf(updateColName) + 1; 
    if (dateCol > 0 && actRow > 1 && editColumn == updateCol) 
    {
      var cell = sheet.getRange(actRow, dateCol);
      var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), timezone, timestamp_format);
      cell.setValue(date);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: For some reason I'm getting an error saying that it cannot read the property "source"

Comment: You cannot run these functions manually you have to run with a  trigger.  If you run them manually the event object is not there to provide event.source and event.range. So don't run these manually instead edit the appropriate ranges to see if it works.  I presumed  that you knew that since you already had the function.

Comment: I see. I just added a trigger. The trigger is on edit, from spreadsheet, on edit.   I saved the function and went to the spreadsheet. When I edited the contents in the PM Status column it is still not producing a timestamp in the "Date Update" column.

Comment: should there be a "(" where you have currently =="All Leads")

Comment: This `if(sheet.getName()=="All Leads")
  {` this look correct to me.

Comment: I've added the trigger for on edit, but i'm still getting the error that it cannot read property source for some reason.

Comment: I modified the code a little.  I changed the column name and the sheet name and went and edited one column and the onEdit() trigger took over and added the time stamp.  Perhaps,  I didn't make myself clear.  If you are running this function with the onEdit() then you don't have to manually add another onEdit.  I'm trying to get you to understand that you cannot get this function to work properly by running the function from the script editor or running from a menu item.  You have to edit the updatecolumn and give it a moment and see if it updates the timestamp for you.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying those things. I'm still having trouble getting it to work. Here's a link to a copy of the doc I'm trying to get this up and running on. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SRo-baurn0a97KsHdGiYqThRK6y9oHG8yzuiCdyCLzY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Your code says the following: `var updateColName = "PM Status";
    var timeStampColName = "Date Update";` and that doesn't seem to agree with your spreadsheet so you need to change your code or change your spreadsheet

Comment: What I am looking for is this: If any cell in the column "PM Status" is edited, then an automatic timestamp will appear in the "Date Update Column" in the same row as the cell that was edited in the PM Status column.

Comment: Column K is named "PM Status".

Comment: Oh your right.  I didn't look far enough. Well, As I said. It works for me so I can't debug that which is not broken.  Yours is broken so I guess you'll have to debug it.  Good luck